# Fatal Error: Could Not find Driver

Tags: php, sql-server, database, pdo, connection

I am trying to connect to SQL Server using PHP PDO however it keeps giving me error. And, i already have file `php_pdo_sqlsrv_53nts.dll` in following directory xampp->php

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not
>   find driver' in C:\xampp\htdocs\config.php:35 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\config.php(35): PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:server=C...',
>   'username...', 'pass') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\config.php
>   on line 35

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
      $serverName ="serverName";
            $dbName="databaseName";
            $username="userName";
            $password="passWrord";

            $connection = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database=$dbName",  "$username", "$password");

       if( $connection )
 {
     echo "Connection established.\n";
   }
else
  {
   echo "Connection could not be established.\n";
   die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  }



?>
```

Is there something wrong i am doing? 
Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found xampp and wamp a pain to use mssql and sqlite drivers, I found the best option was to use the in built iis server in windows http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/server.aspx and download the driver here http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-mysql-for-php-applications-on-iis-7-and-above

If you don't want to move over to iis make sure that the dll file has been loaded into the php.ini file, check to see if the following file extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53nts.dll is included and not commented in your php.ini file